# Rigify mesh skinning problem

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify, parent

I imported a character (with append), and I joined the hair, body, and feet together using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. I applied the scale, rotation, and location using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and everything was fine, and when I generated the rig, it worked perfectly. However, now that I've skinned the mesh, half of the character has disappeared. Here are some screenshots:

Before skinning:

[image]

After skinning:
[image]

Comment: I think with rigify you need to parent and weight paint to the basic mesh before you generate the final rig.

Comment: Could you upload and link the .blend to your question http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the problem. After some research on the 'net, the solution that worked for me was to enable *Auto Run Python Scripts* in File > User Preferences.